# final and private static

Tags: java, static, private, final

I read that doing:

```
public final void foo() {}
```

is equals to:

```
private static void foo() {}
```

both meaning that the method is not overridable!

But I don't see the equivalence if a method is private it's automatically not
accessible...

Comment: Be aware that (somewhat counter-intuitively) *private* means private to the class, not private to the object.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's true that you can not `@Override` either method. You can only `@Override` a non-`final` *instance* method.

- If it's `final`, then there's no way you can `@Override` it
- If it's `static`, then it's not an *instance* method to begin with

It's *NOT* true that they're "equal", because one is `private static`, and the other is `public final`.

- They have different accessibility level
- The *instance* method requires an instance to invoked upon, the *class* method doesn't
- The *class* method can not refer to *instance* methods/fields from the `static` context

You can not `@Override` a `static` method, but you can *hide* it with another `static` method. A `static` method, of course, does not permit dynamic dispatch (which is what is accomplished by an `@Override`).

#### References

- [JLS 8.4. Method Declarations](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4)

  - [8.4.3.2 static Methods](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.3.2)
  - [8.4.3.3 final Methods](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.3.3)
  - [8.4.8 Inheritance, Overriding, and Hiding](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.8)

    - [8.4.8.1 Overriding (by Instance Methods)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.8.1)
    - [8.4.8.2 Hiding (by Class Methods)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.8.2)

#### Related questions

- [Polymorphism vs Overriding vs Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154577/polymorphism-vs-overriding-vs-overloading)
- [Why doesn’t Java allow overriding of static methods ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods)
- [Static methods and their overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521450/static-methods-and-their-overriding)
- [When do you use Java’s @Override annotation and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why)

Comment: Also, the public final method can override some superclass method, while the private static, being static, can not.

Answer (score 2):

Neither can be overridden, but for very different reasons. The first is a public nonstatic method, while the secod is static. So the first is not overridable only because it has been declared final, while the second, being static, can never be overridden.

Note that from the first you can access nonstatic members of the class, while from second you can't. So they are used in very different ways, thus are not "equal".