# Can we override static method in Java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why can’t static methods be abstract in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370962/why-cant-static-methods-be-abstract-in-java)
>   [Static methods and their overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521450/static-methods-and-their-overriding)
>   [Why doesn’t Java allow overriding of static methods ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods)

Can we override static method in Java?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods

Answer (score 4):

No. Static methods are tied to the class they're defined in. They're invoked through the class, not through an object, and there is no dynamic dispatch where overriding could happen.

You're probably confused because Java allows you to invoke static methods through an object reference. That's generally considered a design error, and it does not work like invoking instance methods, because the *compile-time* type of the reference decides which method gets invoked.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can shadow it.

Comment: Yes, consider it a synonym.