# What purpose does "overriding" main serve in Java?

Tags: java, static, program-entry-point, overriding

this is how we can override main function in java....

```
public class animaltest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
        horse h = new horse();
        h.eat();
    }
}

public class inheritmain extends animaltest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
        System.out.print("main overrided");
    }
}
```

but what is the benefit of overriding main??

Comment: thanku all!! got to learn aa really nice concept...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`static` methods do not override: they are shadowed. There are two different *independent* static methods in that case, namely `animaltest.main` and `inheritmain.main`. (See [Can we override static method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157901/can-we-override-static-method-in-java))

The "advantage" -- if any ;-) -- is that the program can be started/launched from *either* class as both classes implement the [*main method*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html#MAIN):

> The *main method* is similar to the main function in C and C++; it's the entry point for your application and will subsequently invoke all the other methods required by your program.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Overriding is not for `STATIC` functions, overriding is only for member functions which are not static.

In this case, No `POLYMORPHIC` will be observed.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can override main in Java because you don't inherit main from any class in the first place. Hence there is nothing to be overriden.